# Cardinality function proof

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

I need help solving the following exercise:

> Let $X$ be a set with $|X| = n\in \mathbb N_0$, $f:\mathcal P(X) \to \{k\in \mathbb N_0: 0 \leq k \leq n\}$ satisfying
>   a) $\forall Y \in \mathcal P(X), Y \neq \emptyset: f(Y) > 0$
>   b) $\forall Y, Z \in \mathcal P(X): f(Y \cup Z) = f(Y \cap Z) + f((Y \cup Z)\backslash (Y \cap Z))$
>   Show that $\forall Y \in \mathcal P(X): f(Y) = |Y|$

I already proved that $f(\emptyset) = 0$ by choosing $Y = X$ and $Z = \emptyset$ using the second rule, but I don't know how to continue from here, since I know nothing about the cardinality but that it's $>0$ for all $Y \neq \emptyset$. Would appreciate any hint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT: Show first that if $A,B\subseteq X$ are disjoint, then $f(A\cup B)=f(A)+f(B)$. Then show by induction on $k$ that if $A_1,\ldots,A_k$ are pairwise disjoint, $f\left(\bigcup_{i=1}^kA_k\right)=\sum_{i=1}^kf(A_i)$. Finally, let $X=\{x_k:k=1,\ldots,n\}$, and consider $f(X)=f\left(\bigcup_{k=1}^n\{x_k\}\right)$, bearing in mind that the codomain of $f$ is $\{0,1,\ldots,n\}$.

Comment: How can I show that $f(A \cup B) = f(A) + f(B)$ though? I can only proof it when $A \cup B = X$.

Comment: @lappen68: Apply (b) to the sets $A$ and $A\cup B$.

Comment: I got it. You are awesome, Brian!

Comment: @lappen68: Glad it helped!

Comment: Okay I tried out a lot now, but I still wasn't able to proof it. Is it possible to restrict $A, B$ to $A \cup B = X$? Or could you show me how to proof it without that property? I tried with $f(A \cup \emptyset)$ and $f(A \cup B)$ but I couldn't get to a nice result... Would be really nice of you!

Comment: @lappen68: If $A$ and $B$ are disjoint, let $C=A\cup B$. Then $$\begin{align*}f(A\cup B)&=f(C\cup B)\\ &=f(C\cap B)+f\big((C\cup B)\setminus(C\cap B)\big)\\ &=f(B)+f(C\setminus B)\\ &=f(B)+f(A)\;.\end{align*}$$

Comment: Of course, why did I only think of the whole set X rather than any set C... Thanks :)

Comment: @lappen68: You’re welcome.